# PostgreSQL and TSTZRANGE

Tags: postgresql

I am very new to using datetime ranges and after reviewing the documentation am confused as to why the following simple query is not behaving as I expected:

*lifespan = DateTimeRangeField*

```
select id, lifespan 
from companyfeatures
where lifespan && TSTZRANGE('1 Mar 2020', '1 May 2020')
```

I was expecting the result to be only those records whose lifespan falls between '1 Mar 2020' and '1 May 2020' - however, the results include records with a NULL lifespan.

Can some assist or explain where I am going wrong?

**Edit:**
Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name - After digging some more, it appears that the lifespan field had previously been populated with 'empty' or default ranges ie DateTimeTZRange(None, None, '()') - so they are not null. Very messy and I am unable to change this (at this stage). I am thus looking for a way to find the overlap (have points in common) with my specific range dates and ignore the 'empty' ones? Can you assist?

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=69a12b882cae70715e52a6176865ba53)

Comment: There must be something else going on, because the `&&` operator will certainly not return `true` for `null` values: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=231cb73e5a622fab8d218e9c0939cf16

Comment: Thanks for your comment and example. I have updated my question after some digging

Comment: You can't put "none" into a range, do you mean `null` (or maybe `infinity`) ?

Comment: Apologies - yes it is null

Comment: Contrary to conventional wisdom with nulls a range lower or upper bound is null it indicated unbounded on that edge. If both are null then all values fall within the range. See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=eabc81fc3137ce09254a8c3481aa4fb7).

Answer (score 1):

You can filter those in the WHERE clause

```
select id, lifespan 
from companyfeatures
where upper(lifespan) IS NOT NULL 
  and lower(lifespan) IS NOT NULL
  and lifespan && TSTZRANGE('2020-03-01', '2020-05-01')
```